# How to tar up multiple folders, some recursively, some non-recursively

Tags: linux, tar

I have a list of directories. Some of the directories require them to be tared up recursively, other require only the file that exist in that directory, no subdirectories:
Using the directory/files below as an example, how would my tar command look:

```
/tmp/dir1/ - Recursively
/tmp/dir2/ - Only the files that exist in that directory, no subdirectories
/tmp/dir3/file1 - Only this single file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

First, the directory structure I'm using as an example:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 dir3 -print
dir1
dir1/file1
dir1/file2
dir1/sub_dir1
dir1/sub_dir1/file1
dir2
dir2/file1
dir2/file2
dir2/sub_dir1
dir2/sub_dir1/file1
dir3
dir3/file1
$
```

Next, my solution which consists of three commands:

First command:

```
tar cvf archive.tar dir1
```

Pretty standard. Let's break it up:

- `c` - Create
- `v` - Verbose (let's see what's going on)
- `f` - the filename we want, in our case `archive.tar`
- `archive.tar` - that actual argument to our `f` switch
- `dir1` - what we want to actually tar up

Second command:

```
find dir2 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar rvf archive.tar
```

Let's break it up:

- `find dir2` - Where we want find to search.
- `-maxdepth 1` - Don't go any further down than a depth of 1 (stay at the root of `dir2`)
- `-type f` - Search for files
- `-print0` - Don't print out a newline character at the end, instead use null character. This helps us out if find finds files with whitspace in them.
- `| xargs -0` - The standard input we found with the find command gets thrown here to be executed while respecting our `print0`
- `tar rvf` - The only new switch here is `r`. This is our append option. It adds to our `archive.tar` at the end of it. Not to be confused with the `A` option which is specific to appending additional archives (`.tar`-s).
- `archive.tar` - The tar we want to append to.

  The end of this command is where our stdinput gets used. e.g. `archive.tar <stdinput>`

Third command:

```
tar rvf archive.tar dir3/file1
```

Append to `archive.tar` a single file (`file1`) from `dir3`.

And finally, what the tar looks like after it's created. The `t` option is used to print out it's contents.

```
$ tar tvf archive.tar
drwxrwxr-x mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:01 dir1/file1
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:01 dir1/file2
drwxrwxr-x mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir1/sub_dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir1/sub_dir1/file1
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir2/file1
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir2/file2
-rw-rw-r-- mmallard/mmallard 0 2019-07-18 16:02 dir3/file1
$
```